# Getting NoReverseMatch while click the comment button

Tags: python, django

I was getting that same error while click the like button, But the error was solved..
again after creating comment view and its other staff I'm getting that error again...When I click the comment button then the error appears..I'm very new to Django,,, help me please..
My project models.py, template page, urls.py, views.py are attached herewith

```
**models.py** 
from email.policy import default
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Put a Title")
    blog_content = models.TextField(verbose_name="What is on your mind")
    blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog_images", default = "/default.png")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "blog_comment" )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "user_comment")
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment


class Like(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "blog_liked")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "user_liked")


class Unlike(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "blog_unliked")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "user_unliked")


**blog_page.html**
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <h2>{{blog.title}}</h2>
    <img src="{{blog.blog_image.url}}" alt="" width="630px" height="300px">
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    {{blog.blog_content|linebreaks}}
</div>
{% if not liked and not unliked %}
<h4> <a href="{% url 'like' blog.pk %}">Like</a> </h4>
<h4><a href="{% url 'unlike' blog.pk %}">Unlike</a></h4>

{% elif unliked %}
<h4> <a href="{% url 'like' blog.pk %}">Like</a> </h4>
{% elif liked %}
<h4><a href="{% url 'unlike' blog.pk %}">Unlike</a></h4>
{% endif %}

<div>
    <h4>
        Comments:
    </h4>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div>
        {{ user }} <br>
        <h5>{{ comment }}</h5>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- <h6>Add your comment:</h6> -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}} <br>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'comment' %}">Comment</a>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock content %}




**urls.py**
from django.urls import path
from blog_app import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("blog_page/<str:pk>/", views.blog_view, name='blog_page'),
    path("like/<str:pk>/", views.like, name="like"),
    path("unlike/<str:pk>/", views.unlike, name="unlike"),
    path("comment/", views.comment, name="comment"),

]



**views.py**    
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Blog, Comment, Like, Unlike
from . forms import CommentForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    

    context = {'blogs': blogs}
    return render(request, 'blog_app/home.html', context)





def blog_view(request, pk):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(blog=blog)
    context = {"blog": blog, "comments": comments, "form":form}
    return render(request, 'blog_app/blog_page.html', context)
    
def like(request, pk):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=pk)
    user = request.user
    liked, like = Like.objects.get_or_create(blog=blog, user=user)
    context = {"liked" : liked, "blog": blog }
    return render(request, "blog_app/blog_page.html", context)

def unlike(request, pk):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=pk)
    user = request.user
    unliked, unlike = Unlike.objects.get_or_create(blog=blog, user=user)
    context = {"unliked" : unliked, 'blog': blog}
    return render(request, "blog_app/blog_page.html", context)


def comment(request):
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {}
    return render(request, "blog_app/blog_page.html", context)
```

Comment: Please post the error as it will help debug where your trying to send your request to vs where your urls.py is configuring the route. Also, its not clear from where the error originates from.

Comment: Are you by any chance creating a new blog?

Comment: File "D:\Project\Django Project\My Project\Blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\Django Project\My Project\Blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'like' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['like/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']
[27/Oct/2022 17:18:48] "GET /comment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 177907

Comment: please post that as a code block in the question, not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Your comment button is just a link, is it normal ? I think, you want to submit your form when you click on?

```html
<div>
    <h4>
        Comments:
    </h4>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div>
        {{ user }} <br>
        <h5>{{ comment }}</h5>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- <h6>Add your comment:</h6> -->
    <form action="{% url 'comment' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}} <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And i think, your problem occured because you dispolay this template from comment view without set blog in context data.

```
def blog_view(request, pk):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(blog=blog)
    context = {"blog": blog, "comments": comments, "form":form}
    return render(request, 'blog_app/blog_page.html', context)


def comment(request):
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("blog_page", pk=form.instance.blog.pk)
        return HttpResponse(status_code=400) # error case
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status_code=501) # try to GET page
```

Better solution is to pass blog pk in the url for being able to render page with error:

```
path("blog/<int:pk>/comment/", views.comment, name="comment")
```

```
    <form action="{% url 'comment' blog.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}} <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Comment</button>
    </form>
```

```
def comment(request, pk):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("blog_page", pk=blog.pk)
    return render(request, "...", {"blog": blog, "form": form})
```

Comment: No, this is not correct, look at the image he posted. It relates to reversing the `like` url pattern

Comment: @Swift yes because the view comment display again same view without blog context data, i wrote it

Comment: yes I want to submit my form when I click...but its not happening

Comment: at first I need that blog with id,,,and then pass it through context??????

Comment: @ShishirRehan yes my code resolve this problem and i propose solution for context blog data, but it seems there is a bad intial build of view or urls. you do not have access to blog in case of form error

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_app_comment.blog_id

Comment: @ShishirRehan you have to set a blog field in your modelForm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249110/discussion-between-shishir-rehan-and-lucas-grugru).